# Execute a jQuery function after 2 others were finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

In my project I have two functions that retrieve respectively the number of completed tasks, and the number of uncompleted tasks. (I use NeDB but it does not matter).

After that, I want to add together these two numbers.

Here is my code :

```js
var completed = 0
  , uncompleted = 0;

// Get completed tasks
db.find({ completed: true }, function (err, tasks) {
   completed = tasks.length;
   console.log(completed); // output 7
});

// Get uncompleted tasks
db.find({ completed: false }, function (err, tasks) {
   uncompleted = tasks.length;
   console.log(uncompleted); // output 3
});

// This line is executed before the lines above
console.log(completed+uncompleted); // output 0 (I would like to output 10)
```

As you see the last line output 0 because it is executed before the two functions have finished.

So my question is how to make the last line output 10 ?

I think I have to use promises, but I read a lot of topics on SO and there is a lot of different approaches (with promise, then, done, deffered, array of promises, functions in variables ...) so I'm a little bit lost.

I wanted to know what is the correct way to do that :)

I tried this code, but I think I am completely mistaken ...

```js
   var completed = 0
     , uncompleted = 0;
       
   // Get completed tasks
   var getCompleted = function(){
     return db.find({ completed: true }, function (err, tasks) {
       completed = tasks.length;
       console.log(completed); // output 7
     });
   }

   // Get uncompleted tasks
   var getUncompleted = function(){
     return db.find({ completed: false }, function (err, tasks) {
       uncompleted = tasks.length;
       console.log(uncompleted); // output 3
     });
   }
   
   var promises = [];

   promises.push(getCompleted());
   promises.push(getUncompleted());

   $.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
     console.log(completed+uncompleted); // output 0
   });
```

Comment: does `db.find` return a promise?

Comment: I did not fully understand how promises work but I think no, db.find does not return a promise (there is no mention of "promise" in NeDB documentation) Edit: I checked the NeDB Github and I am sure that db.find does not return a promise ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Promises, first you'll need to promisify any asynchronous tasks that don't return a promise

In your case

## A

```
function dbFindPromise(db, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
        db.find(params, (err, result) => {
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        })
    )
};
```

Then, using this promisified db find, your code can be written as

## B

```
Promise.all([
    dbFindPromise(db, { completed: true }).then(tasks => {
        console.log(tasks.length);
        return tasks.length;
    }),
    dbFindPromise(db, { completed: false }).then(tasks => {
        console.log(tasks.length);
        return tasks.length;
    })
]).then(([completed, uncompleted]) => {
    console.log(completed + uncompleted);
});
```

---

> Alternatively, using jquery Deferred and when - first the "promisified" function

## C

```
function dbFindPromise(db, params) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    db.find(params, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Then to use it:

## D

```
$.when(dbFindPromise(db, { completed: true }).then(tasks => {
        console.log(tasks.length);
        return tasks.length;
    }), dbFindPromise(db, { completed: false }).then(tasks => {
        console.log(tasks.length);
        return tasks.length;
    })
).done((completed, uncompleted) => {
    console.log(completed + uncompleted);
});
```

So, native promises, code A and B, jquery Promises is code C and D

But, you can use code A with code D or code C with code B - because Promises should behave the same regardless of where they came from (in this case, native vs jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I have a "syntax error Unexpected token =" at the first line ?

Comment: yes, because the = shouldn't be there - typo on my part (I started writing it like `var dbFindPromise = arrow notation` then switched it to `function dbFindPromise` and forgot to remove the `=` and arrow notation

Comment: It works perfectly ! Thank you very much. (but I actually use the code C with the code D) there is a mistake ? because you said use A with D or C with B ? :p Edit: Oh I just understand your last paragraph, so it's normal that both works with both (bad english level). Thanks again, I put the topic as resolved

Answer (score 0):

The `NeDB` library you are using does not return promises - you can perform your work in nested callbacks like this:

```
db.find({completed: true}, function(err, completeTasks) {
  db.find({completed: false}, function(error, incompleteTasks) {
    console.log(completeTasks.length + incompleteTasks.length);
  });
})
```

Comment: of course, this doesn't make the two db.find requests in parallel, like in the original code :p